# Trying to join different table from different database in the localhost, Used MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Explanations:**
*First of all im new in the database field, i got system from my boss, my boss ask me to create dashboard based on the data from database, but some data need to join other table in different database. In my case i need to fetch data at column score from table rank in 4 different database which is "virtualexam, virtualexam1, virtualexam2, virtualexam3,"
. I had try and search but i cant display the data into the table, your advice and recommendation really appreciate it.. Thank you for you kindness*

**Error picture**
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArXn6.png)

**Database Table Picture** **Dummy data*

[db.virtualexam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ7d0.png)

[db.virtualexam1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHY45.png)

[db.virtualexam2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwTUW.png)

[db,virtualexam3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueagp.png)

**my query**

```
                <?php
                      $sql = "SELECT virtualexam.rank.id, virtualexam.rank.username,
                      virtualexam.rank.score AS score, virtualexam1.rank.score AS 'score1', virtualexam2.rank.score AS 'score2', virtualexam3.rank.score AS 'score3' 
                      SUM(virtualexam.rank.score + virtualexam1.rank.score + virtualexam2.rank.score + virtualexam3.rank.score ) AS 'total' 
                      FROM virtualexam.rank
                      JOIN virtualexam1.rank ON virtualexam.rank.username =  virtualexam1.rank.username, 
                      JOIN virtualexam2.rank ON virtualexam1.rank.username =  virtualexam2.rank.username, 
                      JOIN virtualexam3.rank ON virtualexam2.rank.username =  virtualexam3.rank.username
                      GROUP BY id ";


                      $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    ?>
```

**display in the table**

```
  <tbody>

                                        <?php
                                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                            {
                                                echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row['score1'] . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row['score2'] . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row['score3'] . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>";
                                             
                                                
                                               
                                                echo "</tr>";
                                                }
                                                            
                                          ?>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Please post the error message as text instead of a .png. Follow [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $sql = "SELECT virtualexam.rank.id, virtualexam.rank.username,
    virtualexam.rank.score AS score, virtualexam1.rank.score AS 'score1', virtualexam2.rank.score AS 'score2', virtualexam3.rank.score AS 'score3',
    SUM(virtualexam.rank.score + virtualexam1.rank.score + virtualexam2.rank.score + virtualexam3.rank.score ) AS 'total' 
    FROM virtualexam.rank

    JOIN virtualexam1.rank ON (virtualexam.rank.username =  virtualexam1.rank.username)

    JOIN virtualexam2.rank ON (virtualexam2.rank.username =  virtualexam1.rank.username)

    JOIN virtualexam3.rank ON (virtualexam3.rank.username =  virtualexam2.rank.username)

    GROUP BY virtualexam.rank.username";
```

Comment: thank you for your time and kindness, already trying your code and compare from my old code but it does not working. Even thought check syntax error, still same error message come out

Comment: can you share screen shot of your databases and table, will be helpfull.

Comment: I have updated code please execute again hopefully it will works

Comment: Great its work! Thank you for you time and kindness, I felt not complete if i dont know where is my mistake, If you dont mind please explain your code to me in simple word. Thank you